# React HOC to handel child component API failure

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics-api, react-hoc

I am using a component from a library which accepts an `accessToken` as a props. Like 
`<AnalyticsChart accesstoken={this.state.token} />` and based on the token, it makes an API call and renders an UI based on the result. Now, if the `accesstoken` has expired, it doesn't have a callback props to notify the the parent component (over which I have complete control).

SO, is there a way to build an Higher Order Component which could listen for API requests made by the child components, or just maybe watch for DOM changes to see if nothing is rendered for a long time?

Example-

```
export default MyComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        <AnalyticsComponent accesstoken={this.props.token} />
    }
}
```

Comment: What about use `componentDidUpdate` in your `MyComponent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `withFetch` HOC to inject your modified fetch function or a simple custom hook.

**1. HOC Implementation**

```
// UNTESTED
function withFetch(Component) {
  return function(props) {
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);

    // modified fetch
    const doFetch = React.useCallback((url, options) => {
      try {
        fetch(url, options)
        // proceed if successful
      } catch(error) {
        setError(true);
        // TODO: add other states to store error message
      }
    }, [params])

    // run effect every time there's fetch error
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (error) {
        // TODO: do something
      }
    }, [error]);

    return <Component fetch={doFetch} {...props} />
  }
}

const EnhancedComponent = withFetch(MyComponent)
return <EnhancedComponent accessToken="some token" />
```

**2. Custom Hook**

```
function hasFetchError(url, options) {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function doFetch() {
      try {
        await fetch(url, options)
        // do something with response
      } catch(error) {
        setError(true);
      }
    }
    doFetch();
  }, [url, options])

  return error;
}

// Usage:
function MyComponent(props) {
  const error = hasFetchError(props.url, props.options);
  if (error) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using hooks, why not make a custom hook instead of an HOC that uses hook

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri true. just being in context with OP asking for HOC. I've added a simple custom hook just for brevity.

Comment: can you do a callback within useEffect like that?

also, i don't think the first one will work because you're using hooks within a callback. i'm fighting with that right now